# How to insert an empty row before a specific cell in a large spreadsheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large spreadsheet, about 200,000 rows, and I want to insert a row after every 100th serial number but *not by the row number*.

I found a macro that inserts by row number, but that is not what I want.

Comment: A good start would be you posting that macro.

Comment: Here i found that Macro,,,  http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090606111327AAPaGf7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
Dim theRange As Range
Dim idx As Long

Set theRange = Sheet1.UsedRange ''Or other appropriate sheet
idx = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ''Where A is your serial number

For i = idx To 1 Step -1

    If theRange.Cells(i, 1) Mod 100 = 0 Then
       Rows(i).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thank you sir, By doing this a row is inserted in the first column only, but i want to insert an empty row at that point(before 101 row) for all the columns.

Comment: I have changed to insert a full row.

Comment: @user1917229 please do not edit tags based on the answers provided. An answer may indicate to use/not use early binding but the original tag is appropriate for [**THIS QUESTION**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903530/combine-2-scripting-dictionaries-in-vbscript)