# Combine 2 Scripting.Dictionaries or Collections of Key/Item pairs

Tags: performance, vba, dictionary, collections, vbscript

Is there a more efficient way to combine 2 dictionaries in VBScript / VBA? I wrote the function below, but I'm worried about the performance impact:

```
Function MergeDicts(Dct1, Dct2)
    'Merge 2 dictionaries. The second dictionary will override the first if they have the same key

    Dim Res, Key

    Set Res = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each Key In Dct1.Keys()
        Res.Item(Key) = Dct1(Key)
    Next

    For Each Key In Dct2.Keys()
        Res.Item(Key) = Dct2(Key)
    Next

    Set MergeDicts = Res
End Function
```

Comment: Do you actually need to use a `Dictionary`? I mean do you need the `keys` only or `key/value` pairs?

Comment: @mehow, I do need the `key/value` pairs, but even if I only needed the `keys`, what would be the alternative?

Comment: @neelsg, do your keys and values are standart types or values can contain objects?

Comment: @simoco, keys and values are both strings

Comment: @neelsg, I've tried to store values/keys in arrays and then operate arrays while merging (instead dictionaries), but the performance even worse. (`0.046875` for your algorithm and `0.0703125` with arrays). Btw, I've tried it with two dictionaries with **10000** key/value pairs each. And they are merged for `0.046875` second (using early binding as in my answer). With late binding I got `0.069841` seconds. I don't thing it's too much for 10000 pairs. Your algorithm is fine.

Comment: @neelsg, btw you have a little typo: `Res = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` should be `Set Res = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`:)

Comment: @simoco, oops. I think I deleted it when I copy/pasted

Comment: @DmitryPavliv did you calculate new instances of every array in eveyr loop iteration, or did you calculated them once and saved to variables? from common sense early bindings plus index-based iterating two array VARIABLES (rather than functions) shoul;d be the fastest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to improve performance, don't use *late binding* :

```
Dim Res
Set Res = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

use *early binding* instead.

Add reference to `Microsotf Scripting Runtime` library (go to *TOOLS->REFERENCES*)

[image]

and then use:

```
Dim Res as New Dictionary
```

Your algorithm is fine. Merging two dictionaries (each contains **10000** key/value pairs) takes on my machine `0.046875` seconds for early binding and `0.069841` for late binding.

Comment: Well, there is a more efficient way to merge collections ;) See my answer

Comment: @mehow - well *I* just dont see, why/how ArrayList's .AddRange disputes my claim that you need loops in case of Dictionaries.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner see my last comment below my own answer. It handles the adding of collections in no time.

Comment: @mehow - sorry for adding my comment to the wrong post. Ad rem: If the specs ask for a dictionary (i.e. access by key (not numerical index) and no duplicates) then using an Arraylist is a serious mistake even if the operation fast.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner while I can partially agree with you(specs may be limited to use a dictionary structure), the OP is asking for the efficient version... Since `Dictionary` implements ICollection it's down to **what you are actually going to do with the data in your**  **Dictionary**. AFAIK Stack Overflow is a place where professionals learn from each other. When I disagree with someone I give my own version, how I would do it - pros and const listed. I honestly do not want you to feel that you're wrong. If others agree with you they will upvote your answer. Please, no hard feelings :)

Comment: @mehow - for what it is worth: I agree totally with you and my feelings are soft.

Comment: @simoco - please mention explicitly that your single loop merge will *change* the first source dictionary.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, you're right, missed that. I've deleted my upd part of answer.

Comment: Note that `Dim Res as New Dictionary` works in Excel VBA but throws an error in Word VBA. I recommend just always using `Dim Res as New Scripting.Dictionary`, as this will work with all `Applications`.

Comment: i think that using two arrays would still be faster that using N x hash-searches, see the draft code in @Ekkehard.Horner answer comments

Answer (score -2):

If you really need the merged dictionary, you can't avoid the CreateObject, the two loops, and the assignments. You could try whether counted loops - `For i = 0 To UBound(dictX.Keys())` - is faster. A slight change of specs - keep value of first dictionary - would allow an experiment wrt. checking Res.Exists(Dct2-Key) to avoid 'unnecessary' assignments.

Perhaps an inlining

```
If Dct1.Exists(key) Then
...
Else
   If Dct2.Exists(key) Then
...
```

is more efficient, but whether is's a good idea obviously depends on your script in toto.

Comment: I disagree(-1) because 1. you can avoid CreateObject by adding references to Microsoft Scripting Runtime then use `Dim d as Dictionary` - early binding is always faster. 2. On collections `for each` loops are much faster than loops using *iterators*.

Comment: `For i = 0 To UBound(dictX.Keys())` - this feels a bad pattern. Both `.Keys` and `.Items` are potentially very expensive functions. If anything there to be vairables and functions should only be calculated once. `Dim i, Ks, Vs : Ks = dictSource.Keys : Vs = dictSource.Items: for i = LBound(Ks) to UBound(Ks) : dictDest.Items(Ks(i)) = Vs(i): Next` - something like that